# OOP in Processing, how should I structure my classes?

Tags: java, class, oop, subclass, processing

Currently I am trying to build an application that will visualize an xml tree in Processing. I am new to Processing (and Java for that matter) and I am having some problems getting my ideas into objects. Currently I have a Node class:

```
class Node {

//DATA
color textColor;
color boxColor;
float xpos = width/2;
float ypos = 100;
float nodeWidth;
float nodeHeight;
boolean overBox = false;
boolean active = false;
PFont font;

//CONSTRUCTOR
Node(){
  textColor = color(0);//sets text color
  boxColor = color(244);//sets box color
  font = createFont("Gil Sans", 16, true);
  textFont(font,50);
  nodeWidth = textWidth("Modernism");//INPUT TEXT
  nodeHeight = textAscent();//?textDescent()?

  rectMode(RADIUS);
}

void displayText(){
  fill(textColor);
  text("Modernism",xpos-nodeWidth/2,ypos+nodeHeight/2.3);
}

void displayBox(){
  //stroke(boxColor);
  noStroke();
  noFill();
  rect(xpos, ypos, nodeWidth/2, nodeHeight/2);

  //FOR DEBUGGING OVERBOX
  //stroke(135);
  //point(300,200);
}

void overBox(){
  if(mouseX > xpos-nodeWidth/2 && mouseX < xpos+nodeWidth/2 &&
     mouseY > ypos-nodeHeight/2 && mouseY < ypos+nodeHeight/2) {
    overBox = true;  
  }else{
    overBox = false;
  }
}

 void clicked(){

   if(active) {
   //If box was already clicked, trigger response
     textColor = color(0);
     overBox = false; 
     active = false;
   }

   if(overBox) {
   //checks to see if click happened within bounds of box, makes active
     textColor = color(100);
     active = true;
   }
 }

  boolean activeCheck(){
    if(active == true){
     return true;
    }else{
     return false; 
    }
  }
```

}

And then I want a connection cable drawn between the parent and children of the XML document:

```
class Connectors{
//DATA
color lineColor;
int lineWeight;
int lineX1 = 12;
int lineY1 = 155;
int lineX2 = 12;
int lineY2 = 475;

//CONSTRUCTOR
Connectors(){
  lineColor = color(0);
  lineWeight = 2;
}

//FUNCTIONALITY
void displayConnection(){
  stroke(lineColor);
  strokeWeight(lineWeight);
  line(lineX1,lineY1,lineX2,lineY2);
}
}
```

This is all very rough, but I was wondering how the connections should relate to the nodes. To build the connections, it needs to know where it's parent node is located. Should the connections be a subclass of it's respective node?

Comment: subclass => "is a", like a `Car` class might be a subclass of a `Vehicule` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should favor [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) over inheritance in this case. That is, have the `Connector` keep a reference to two `Node`s.

```
public class Connector {

    // other members
    private Node firstNode;
    private Node secondNode;

    public Connector(Node firstNode, Node secondNode) {
        this.firstNode = firstNode;
        this.secondNode = secondNode;
    }

}
```

Now the `Connector` knows about the two `Node`s it connects.

The reason why you want to do this is the fact that `Node`s and `Connector`s don't share a lot in common. We have conventions for how we can translate OOP relationships into English.

- Use "is a" to describe inheritance.
- Use "has a" to describe aggregation and composition.

Which makes more sense? "`Connector` is a `Node`," or "`Connector` has a `Node`"?

Now, you might want to make an abstract parent class, or even better, an interface, for both of `Connector` and `Node` if they do share some things in common, such as the ability to draw them.

```
public interface MyDrawable {

    /**
     *  Draw this object on the "processing" canvas
     *  note: 2rs2ts does not know anything about the "processing" library
     */
    public void draw();

}

// another file...

public class Connector implements MyDrawable {

    // all of the other stuff

    public void draw() {
        stroke(lineColor);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Inheritance means that you pull everything the parent class does into the child class. (That's the reason for the keyword `extends`.) If there's stuff about `Node`s that is totally separate from stuff about `Connector`s, don't have one inherit from the other. If you do want to gain OOP abstraction, separate the commonalities into an interface or a common parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want build your XML parser or tree as a exercise, if not use some java library to walk the xml tree. There are a lot of libraries to do that.

Don't represent connection as a subclass of Node, in no way. A connection is not a node. You can represent your Tree as a special graph, the node is the vertex and the connection is the edges.

You have the option to make the node has other nodes, and that is a connection.

Like this

```
public class Node {
  Node parent;
  Node left;
  Node right;
  // Or if there is N Connections, or as we say in tree leafs
  List<Node> connections;
}
```

Then you use an algorithm to walk the nodes and display the connections starting form the initial node (header), you could use list or hashtables to represent your tree as a collection of nodes. If you study a little of Graph theory or Algorith and Structural Data in computer cience you can do that.